# How can I identify ARIMA model for this data?

Tags: time-series, arima, residuals

My data, its ACF, PACF looks like this[image]
The data is daily data and has period of 365 days though with varying mean. 
I tried fitting ARIMA (0,1,1) model (following suggestion from ESACF), it cannot pass the Ljung-Box test and the residual distribution does not have normal distribution.

When to take into account seasonality I add seasonal differencing 
identify var=x(1,365)
the data looks like this-
[image]

When I fit (0,1,1) (0,1,1)_365 seasonal ARIMA model to it, the residual diagnostic again cannot pass the Ljung-Box test. I also tried taking logarithm of x, but no luck there either.

No matter which model I fit, It cannot pass the Ljung-Box test

Any suggestion on how to model this data so the residuas would be white noise?

Comment: Your series is clearly effected by deterministic structure such as pulses ,perhaps holiday effects, perhaps week of the year , perhaps month of the year , perhaps day-of-the month etc.. ...If you post your data I will try and be more specific.;Post it as a column , specifying the beginning date and country of origin.

Comment: Thank you so much for you kind offer. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcvgv6x85brytni/data.xlsx?dl=0 would be the link to the excel file with data and date. Also the data is water inflow of a reservoir (country of origin USA), so holidays are not relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your 1461 observations (4 years) into AUTOBOX ( a software package that I have helped to develop) and obtained the ACF of the original series [image] . Standard (i.e. almost always naive ) model identification strategy assumes no outliers/level shifts/seasonal pulses/special causes are present. AUTOBOX developed a first-pass model that identified a plethora of pulse outliers for the months of September and October for the first 2 years.

We have seen retails sales buildup starting about Nov 15th of each year and lasts about 60 days requiring model structure to deal with this recurring phenomenon. In a similar way I suggested that a similar variable be considered/ used for a 75 day window stating at 9/1 for each of the first 2 years.

The fully resolved model combining this "special variable" , month of the year and ARIMA structure and allowances for identified pulses is here in two images [image] and [image]  . The statistical summary is here [image] . The residuals from the model are plotted here [image] with an ACF here [image]. The Actual/Fit and Forecast graph is here [image] with the Actual and Cleansed presented here [image]

Finally the ARIMA model (in concert with other structure) is essentially a (0,1,0)(0,0,0) as the AR(1) coefficient is nearly 1.0 .

EDITED AFTER OP REEQUSTED SOME ADDITIONAL DETAILS OF THE ANALYSIS"

I added one series call M_DYN175 and placed 0's everywhere except for 9/1/09 and 9/1/2010 . For example this is a snapshot around 9/1/09 . AUTOBOX has a feature that enables a "long polynomial" .. in this case up to lag75 providing a shortcut to estimate 75 individual coefficients .In this example some 46 were found to be statistically significant and the others deleted. You can effect the same solution by creating 46 individual pulse indicators (0/1) in your regression model. Now as to how PULSE VARIABLES (OUTLIERS) were found this is accomplished by enabling Intervention Detection procedures following Tsay  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/for.3980070102/abstract ( a feature of AUTOBOX and elsewhere ).

[image]

Comment: I have accepted the answer and upvoted it. Unfortunately since I do have enough reputation, it will not be shown publicly. I just need one explanation. Could you explain how you formulated and included the special variable from the images that you have provided? Thank you.

Comment: and how did you include allowance for pulses?

Comment: If you wish to get more specific  details (beyond the normal  interest of the group) you can contact me.

Comment: Actually I have asked another question in this forum, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245280/how-to-find-cross-correlation-of-a-response-variable-with-three-independent-pred can you please look into it if you don't mind?

Comment: You have so so so so many questions !..... why don't u call me so we can have a dialogue .. I will be glad to clear up ur questions